# Can I do an UPDATE using a linked active directory server?

Tags: sql-server, ldap, linked-server, ldap-query

I linked my SQL Server 2008 to Active Directory like this:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
        'ADSI', 
        'Active Directory Services 2.5', 
        'ADSDSOObject', 
        'adsdatasource'
```

Then I can query my phone number like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY( 
    ADSI, 
    'SELECT DisplayName, TelephoneNumber from ''LDAP://ad1/DC=directagents,DC=local'' WHERE DisplayName=''Aaron Anodide''')
where not DisplayName is null
order by DisplayName
```

But I have not been able to change my phone number, as this causes an error:

```
SELECT * FROM
OPENQUERY( 
    ADSI, 
    'UPDATE TelephoneNumber from ''LDAP://ad1/DC=directagents,DC=local'' SET TelephoneNumber=''136'' WHERE DisplayName=''Aaron Anodide''')
```

Error:

> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   An error occurred while preparing the query...

Is this possible or is the idea that this is used for read-only access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the SQL Server-to-Active Directory interface is read-only - you can select from AD, but you cannot update it.

See Richard Mueller's [ADO Search Tips](http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOSearchTips.htm) on the topic - he states:

> *Active Directory searches using ADO are very efficient. The provider retrieves records matching your query criteria in one operation,
>   without the need to bind to many objects. However, **the resulting
>   recordset is read-only**, so ADO **cannot be used to modify Active
>   Directory** objects directly. If you need to modify attribute values,
>   you will have to bind to the object.*

Comment: what does 'bind to the object' mean there?

Comment: Call some method in code that *binds* to the object - establishes a "connection" to the object, if you will; not just selects some properties of it. The basic LDAP protocol has a *bind* method, or the ADSI (AD Services Interface) has a `GetObject` method to bind to a single object

Comment: also, `136` may not match the syntax of the `telephoneNumber` attribute even if the objects were writable.